Preserve line break in TextArea
I am trying to remove special characters in my text but preserve line breaks.Though the question has been answered here Preserve line breaks in textarea. However for some reasons its not working in my case which is a textarea.


//Javascript Part
let inputText = document.getElementById('inputTextArea').value;
let cleanedText = inputText
  .replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, function(match) {
    return match === '\n' ? '\n' : ' ';
  })
  .replace(/\s+/g, ' ') // Replace multiple spaces with a single space
  .trim(); // Remove leading and trailing spaces

// Set the cleaned text in the output textarea
document.getElementById('outputTextArea').value = cleanedText;
<textarea id="inputTextArea" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
<button class="clearButton" onclick="removeSpecialCharacters()">Clean Text</button>
<p>Cleaned Text:</p>
<textarea id="outputTextArea" style="white-space: pre-wrap; background: #90d9ab;" rows="10" cols="50" readonly></textarea>




"Uncaught ReferenceError: removeSpecialCharacters is not defined"

Is the "Javascript part" supposed to be in that function name?

match === '\n' will never be true because newlines are included in \s.

replace(/\s+/g, ' ') replaces newlines with spaces, since newlines are whitespace. If you only want to match spaces, use / +/g. And if you only want to match multiple spaces use / {2,}/g

@Barmar Solution of replacing replace(/\s+/g, ' ') with replace(/ +/g, ' ') seems to have worked.
